# Program to create virtual tour of a property?

Tags: video, image-processing

I would like to create a virtual tour of a property. It can be a simple format such as:

Start at front of house picture > options are straight to inside or left/right to garden. 
So forth and so on until the entire place is done with images such as jpeg.

The other option would be a software that does a more complex 360 degree tour.
Also it needs to be able to be embedded in a website.

All advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) or any other photo editor to draw arrows on the photo. Then you can set up a single, simple HTML site that contains exactly one photo with a [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp). The content of such a page will look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TODO</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="relative/path/to/photo.jpg" usemap="#planetmap"/>
    <map name="planetmap">
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
      <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
      <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
    </map>
</body>
</html>
```

You can create the html image map with quite a lot of tools. I think [www.maschek.hu/imagemap](http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap) is ok.

See also: [What is the best tool to create an image map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8971815/562769)

Answer (score 0):

A more complex option would be to use Floorfy's virtual tour software.The team can generate a realistic and interactive tour of a property for you simply from 360º photographs along with added features such as a 3D floor plan and videos. Floorfy gives you the option to rent out the 360º camera therefore making the whole process incredibly simple. You can easily share the tours on both web and mobile platforms. Have a look at an example of Floorfy's virtual tours here: floorfy.com/tour/409627

Website link:https://floorfy.com